# Why the session discontinues after a small idle time?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using colab pro. I am well aware of the session termination for idle period of 1 hr and the max runtime session. But the captcha appears every 15 min, and if I fail so, the discontinues. This is very absurd. I check my session every hour, to avoid the 1hr idle period, but the captcha is bogging me very much. For us data scientists, our code snippet runs for more than 30 mins, I cannot glue to the colab window for that annoying captcha to come again. Instead I am reading the papers in other tab. I set a reminder in my PC for every 45 min, keeping in mind the 1 hr idle period, and the status of my models. If you want to involve captchas please increase the pop time for like 1 hr, this is very annoying, not expected from team Google.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as random
!pip install selenium
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
def autoClickingFunction():
  time.sleep((np.random.random() * 0.05))
  pressKeyNow = Keys.ARROW_DOWN
  time.sleep((np.random.random() * 0.05))
  pressKeyNow = Keys.ARROW_DOWN
```